# How to get latitude and longitude (Chrome mobile)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hey I just want latitude and longitude, but for some reason it does not work in Chrome on my mobile (android), works everywhere else, any clue why...?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function getRedirect(clicked_id){
    var cat = clicked_id;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                window.location.href="near_list.php?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&cat="+cat;
            });
    }   
}
</script>
```

Please help..

Comment: Is Chrome showing you the permission dialog?

Comment: No, nothing is shown. It works on computers with chrome, firefox etc..
and on mobile with firefox

Comment: Any errors in the error console?

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById("latitude ").value = lat;
 document.getElementById("longitude ").value = lon;
```

to get the address:

```
function GetLocation() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
                } else {
                    alert("Request failed.")
                }
            });
        };
```

and even you can get the latitude  and longitude  in alert

Comment: Where do you get those elements from?

Comment: I have to get current position,
' var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
 var longitude = position.coords.longitude;'

This is the bit that wont work, what did I forget..?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to parse these coords through, not very elegant but it works just fine.
I have a file which only have to find coords and parse through to another site

This is how it works
This script will parse latlon

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function pos(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        var newUrl = window.location.search.substring(1);
        window.location.href="near_list.php?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&"+newUrl;

});
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="pos()">
</body>
</html>
```

and the parameters in the url given from script below is kept with the substring(1)

```
<script>

function getRedirect(clicked_id){
            var cat = clicked_id;   
            window.location.href="parse_pos.php?cat="+cat;
        }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php
include_once 'top.php';
?>
<div id="inner_wrapper">
    <div class="near_cat_button" id="bar" onClick="getRedirect(this.id)">Barer</div>
    <div class="near_cat_button" id="restaurant" onClick="getRedirect(this.id)">Restauranter</div>
    <div class="near_cat_button" id="cafe" onClick="getRedirect(this.id)">Cafeer</div>
    <div class="near_cat_button" id="pub" onClick="getRedirect(this.id)">Pubber</div>
    <div class="near_cat_button" id="diskotek" onClick="getRedirect(this.id)">Diskoteker</div>
    <div class="near_cat_button" id=" " onClick="getRedirect(this.id)">Alle</div>
</div>
</div>
```

only way the mobile version of Chrome and Safari would get me latitude and longitude was to call the function in body onLoad""